# Pronunciation problem : The word data : Is it pronounced dā-tə, or ˈda?

Tags: pronunciation

Recently our Educational Ministry is trying to change the way how to evaluate the English skill of candidates of university tests and it hit on Yahoo! Japan's main page.

A comment says, in American English it is pronounced as ˈdā-tə, like, day-ta. On the other hand from my personal experience, I said native American speakers use da-tə, which in my opinion would be correct ( And I got 5 downvotes at my Q&A site simultaneously ).

Which one is correct or more prevalent?

Comment: This might be "answerable with a dictionary" (at least the “correct” part), but here's a post from ELU with data: [Data pronunciation: “dayta” or “dahta”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10155/data-pronunciation-dayta-or-dahta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S. the word is pronounced in at least two different ways, even among people working in the high tech industry where this word is most frequently invoked. Both pronunciations you mentioned are both possible and enjoy similar popularity.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data) includes three different pronunciations.

> /ˈdeɪtə/
>   /ˈdætə/
>   /ˈdɑːtə/

In the U.S. you can definitely hear the first two. /ˈdeɪtə/ is more popular among BrE speakers, or so I have heard.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!